# Raising events from a List(Of T) in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net

I've ported a large VB6 to VB.NET project and while it will compile correctly, I've had to comment out most of the event handlers as to get around there being no array collection for winform objects and so putting the various objects that were in at the collection array into a List object.

For example, in VB6 you could have an array of Buttons. In my code I've got

```
Dim WithEvents cmdButtons As New List(Of Button)
```

(and in the Load event, the List is propagated)

Obviously, you can't fire an event on a container. Is there though a way to fire the events from the contents of the container (which will have different names)?

In the Button creation code, the event name is there, but from what I understand the handler won't intercept as the Handles part of the code is not there (commented out).

Comment: please provide a few more of the **relevant** parts of your code.

Comment: Sure. In the old VB code, you'd have the likes of Public WithEvents txtFields As TextBoxArray. This isn't supported in VB.NET. When you use VS2008, it generates a load of TextBoxes called txtField_0 to txtField_n. This is fine. However, the original code would iterate through the old array and the old array would be used to fire the event. Under VB.NET, the array isn't there, so I'm using List(Of TextBox) as the array container. That's fine and works, but the events are ignored. I'm trying to find if there is a way to fire the events using the code as I have it.

Comment: Just to clarify something: you’re looking at the whole thing the wrong way round. Control arrays were a *workaround* because you couldn’t create *normal* arrays of controls. In .NET this restriction simply doesn’t exist any more so control arrays as a construct have become redundant and were thus removed. And as the answer shows it’s also possible to hook collections up to event handlers – another thing that VB6 didn’t allow (directly; there are some clever hacks to allow this after all).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not exactly sure what you're after, but if you want to be able to add event handlers to some buttons in a container and also have those buttons referenced in a List, you can do something like

```
Public Class Form1

    Dim myButtons As List(Of Button)

    Private Sub AddButtonsToList(targetContainer As Control)
        myButtons = New List(Of Button)

        For Each c In targetContainer.Controls
            If TypeOf c Is Button Then
                Dim bn = DirectCast(c, Button)
                AddHandler bn.Click, AddressOf SomeButton_Click
                myButtons.Add(bn)
            End If
        Next
    End Sub

    Private Sub SomeButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
        Dim bn = DirectCast(sender, Button)
        MsgBox("You clicked " & bn.Name)
    End Sub

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        ' GroupBox1 has some Buttons in it
        AddButtonsToList(GroupBox1)
    End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: That looks exactly what I'm after. Currently, I have in the load myButtons.AddRange(New Buttons() {_btn_0, _btn_1, _btn_2}). I'll add after the addrange a foreach which adds the handler in. Thanks :)